# Java Code Compile Issue

Tags: java

1. Please check the error
2. I have shown the runtime error occurring
3. Please tell what is going wrong in this.
4. This was the problem [Hacker Rank Challenges - Washing Plates ]:https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/101hack41/challenges/washing-plates
5. Error:

   ```
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
       at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
       at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
       at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
       at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
       at Plates.main(Plates.java:17)
   ```
6. Code.

   ```
   import java.util.*;

   public class Plates {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
           //System.out.println("Enter Details");
           String s = in.next();
           int l = s.length();
           int n = s.charAt(0);
           int k = s.charAt(l - 1);
           int arr[][] = new int[n][2];
           for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
               for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                   arr[i][j] = in.nextInt();
               }
           }
           int max = 0;
           int inc[] = new int[n];
           int ded[] = new int[n];
           for(int t = 0; t < n; t++) {
               for(int p = 0; p < 2; p++) {
                   if(p == 0) {
                       inc[t] = arr[t][p];
                   } else if(p == 1) {
                       ded[t] = arr[t][p];
                   }
               }
           }
           int a, b;
           int sum = 0, loss = 0;
           for(a = 0; a < n; a++) {
               for(b = 1; b <= k; b++) {
                   sum = sum + inc[a + 1];
                   loss = loss - ded[a + 1];
               }
               if((sum - loss) > max) {
                   max = sum - loss;
               }
           }
           System.out.println(max);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: It is compiling. It's failing at runtime.

Comment: Not sure what's up but I think your stack trace explicitly says what your error is in this line `arr[i][j] = in.nextInt();`

Comment: It'd be nice to indicate in the source, which is the line mentioned in the exception.

Comment: And next step would be look at the Javadocs of the library method, which throws the exception (in this case `java.util.Scanner.nextInt`) to see why it throws that exception. Then if you don't understand it (though in this case it seems clear enough in the docs...), you might ask *that*, what does it *mean* when `nextInt` throws `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: you should check if there is another element in the collection before trying to do `in.nextInt()` (usually you would use a `while(in.hasNextInt())` as your iterator instead of a `for loop`). `java.util.NoSuchElementException` is thrown at runtime, that's why your code compiles.

Answer (score 6):

HackerRank says:

> The first line contains **two space-separated integers** describing the respective values of `n` (the number of dirty plates) and `k` (the number of plates Harold has time to wash).
>
> - 1 <= `n` <= 20000, 1 <= `k` <= 20000

However, your code is doing something totally different:

```
String s = in.next();
int l = s.length();
int n = s.charAt(0);
int k = s.charAt(l - 1);
```

Since [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) only reads **one** token, `s` would be the String value of the HackerRank value `n`.

Let's say the first line is:

```
7000 20000
```

Your code will read `7000` into `s`, then assign `n = '7'` and `k = '0'`.

The character `'7'` has the ASCII/Unicode numeric value `55`, and the character `'0'` has value `48`. So what you really got was `n = 55` and `k = 48`.

What you should have done, is simply this:

```
int n = in.nextInt();
int k = in.nextInt();
```

---

**UPDATE**

Since the contest is over, you can read the [editorial page](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/101hack41/challenges/washing-plates/editorial) to see a solution. Java doesn't have a [`multiset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/multiset/) (ordered list), but you could use a [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html).

Below is an alternate solution with a lower memory footprint for high values of `k`.

First, assume you can wash all the plates, so sum all the `p` values. If `k >= n`, you're done. Now, for every plate you can't wash, subtract `p` again and also subtract `d`, e.g. subtract `p + d` from the total.

The goal then is to wash the plates with the highest `p + d` value first, so we'll be subtracting smaller values from the total. To do that, build an array of `p + d` values, sort it, and wash/remove/skip the `k` plates with the highest values.

Finally, remember to not return a negative value.

Here it is in compact form:

```
java.util.Scanner in = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
int n = in.nextInt(), k = in.nextInt(), pd[] = new int[n];
long total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int p = in.nextInt(), d = in.nextInt();
    total += p;
    pd[i] = p + d;
}
java.util.Arrays.sort(pd);
for (int i = n - k - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    total -= pd[i];
System.out.println(Math.max(0, total));
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use `nextLine` function to read complete line as an input:

```
String s = in.nextLine();
```

Then split the string on the basis of space.